# How can I login in chrome browser with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I tried logging on my Google account using **selenium python**. But the broswer is giving me error like **This browser or app may not be secure.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NMrq.png)

Is there any way I can sign in or log in to my google account using selenium.